# Bind form field to an object after ngInit has run angular 2 in reactive forms

Tags: forms, angular

We are using a component that contains a form.  We don't want to bind the fields to any specific model at initiation because we want to be able to use it against multiple interfaces.

We are using it as a multiple instance component in a parent componen, like the following example:

```
<component>
 <foo1></foo1>
 <foo2></foot2>
<component>
```

Assuming that the `foo` subcomponents contain a form with the field `Name`

From the parent component, we would like to bind (for example) the `Name` field in `foo1` to `object.foo1.form.name` and `object.foo2.form.name`

But this has to happen in the `ngAfterViewInit` event.

The API says that there is a model property on the `formcontrol` directive.  But can you access that property after post `ngInit`?  If so, how?

Comment: Are you creating a viewRef for your child component in the Parent to access properties?